# How to query a CLOB column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, clob, ora-06502

I'm trying to run a query that has a few columns that are a CLOB datatype. If i run the query like normal, all of those fields just have `(CLOB)` as the value.

I tried using `DBMS_LOB.substr(column`) and i get the error

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

How can i query the CLOB column?

Comment: Typically desktop tools like Toad and PL/SQL Developer do not attempt to preview CLOB columns, but instead display a generic `<CLOB>` placeholder in a clickable text box which pops out into a separate Large Data window when you click it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

When getting the substring of a CLOB column and using a query tool that has size/buffer restrictions sometimes you would need to set the BUFFER to a larger size. For example while using SQL Plus use the `SET BUFFER 10000` to set it to 10000 as the default is 4000.

Running the `DBMS_LOB.substr` command you can also specify the amount of characters you want to return and the offset from which. So using `DBMS_LOB.substr(column, 3000)` might restrict it to a small enough amount for the buffer.

See [oracle documentation](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/A87860_01/doc/appdev.817/a76936/dbms_lo2.htm#1009072) for more info on the substr command

```
    DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (
       lob_loc     IN    CLOB   CHARACTER SET ANY_CS,
       amount      IN    INTEGER := 32767,
       offset      IN    INTEGER := 1)
      RETURN VARCHAR2 CHARACTER SET lob_loc%CHARSET;
```

Comment: I wanted to get clob data, Is there any way to select clob data?

Comment: This function seems to run slow.. is there any other faster alternative?

Comment: Check the dbms_lob.COPY method.

Comment: Oracle Doc link is broken.

Answer (score 88):

This works

```
select DBMS_LOB.substr(myColumn, 3000) from myTable
```

Answer (score 10):

I did run into another condition with HugeClob in my Oracle database.  The `dbms_lob.substr` only allowed a value of 4000 in the function, ex:

```
dbms_lob.substr(column,4000,1)
```

so for my HughClob which was larger, I had to use two calls in `select`:

```
select dbms_lob.substr(column,4000,1) part1, 
       dbms_lob.substr(column,4000,4001) part2 from .....
```

I was calling from a Java app so I simply concatenated part1 and part2 and sent as a email.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 8):

If it's a CLOB why can't we to_char the column and then search normally ?

Create a table

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name varchar2(20), message clob);
```

Create few records in this table

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(1,'Tom','Hi This is Row one');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(2,'Lucy', 'Hi This is Row two');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(3,'Frank', 'Hi This is Row three');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(4,'Jane', 'Hi This is Row four');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(5,'Robert', 'Hi This is Row five');
COMMIT;
```

Search in the clob column

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE where to_char(message) like '%e%';
```

Results

```
ID   NAME    MESSAGE   
===============================  
1    Tom     Hi This is Row one         
3    Frank   Hi This is Row three
5    Robert  Hi This is Row five
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a function and call that function everytime you need to select clob column.

```
create or replace function clob_to_char_func
(clob_column in CLOB,
 for_how_many_bytes in NUMBER,
 from_which_byte in NUMBER)
return VARCHAR2
is
begin
Return substrb(dbms_lob.substr(clob_column
                            ,for_how_many_bytes
                            ,from_which_byte)
            ,1
            ,for_how_many_bytes);
end;
```

and call that function as;

```
SELECT tocharvalue, clob_to_char_func(tocharvalue, 1, 9999)
FROM (SELECT clob_column AS tocharvalue FROM table_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

For big CLOB selects also can be used:

`SELECT dbms_lob.substr( column_name, dbms_lob.getlength(column_name), 1) FROM foo`

Comment: When I use this function I got null value

Comment: Cliff Bender wrote: the dbms_lob.substr only allowed a value of 4000 in the function, maybe that's the issue

Answer (score -1):

To add to  the answer.

```
declare
v_result clob;
begin
---- some operation on v_result
dbms_lob.substr( v_result, 4000 ,length(v_result) - 3999 );

end;
/
```

In `dbms_lob.substr`

`first parameter` is `clob` which you want to extract .

`Second parameter` is how much length of clob you want to extract.

`Third parameter` is from which word you want to extract .

In above example i know my clob size is more than 50000 , so i want last 4000 character .

Comment: how to get a whole character from my clob

Comment: can you brief what you want to achieve?

Answer (score -3):

If you are using SQL*Plus try the following...

```
set long 8000

select ...
```

Comment: how does "set long 8000" help here? please elaborate