# SQLPLUS displaying of tables with CLOB types

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a table which has 3 columns. I have a NUMBER column, CLOB column, and BLOB column. how can i use some sort of SELECT * statement in order to display what I have entered into this table, not just a partial piece of the long character strings i have in there. The only way I know of displaying a long string form a CLOB would be using the DBMS_LOB.substr technique. My BLOB column is currently all NULL so not too worried about displaying that section, Just the number column with its associated CLOB. Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem with `select number_col, clob_col from your_table`?  Maybe your `long` setting is just not large enough and you need to `set long xxxxx` where `xxxxx` is a number of bytes that is larger than the largest CLOB you want to print out?

Answer (score 0):

See here  [How to query a CLOB column in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790379/how-to-query-a-clob-column-in-oracle)

When getting the substring of a CLOB column and using a query tool that has size/buffer restrictions
sometimes you would need to set the BUFFER to a larger size.
For example while using SQL Plus use the SET BUFFER 10000 to set it to 10000 as the default is 4000.

Running the DMBS_LOB.substr command you can also specify the amount of characters you want to return and the offset from which.
 So using DMBS_LOB.substr(column, 3000) might restrict it to a small enough amount for the buffer.

See oracle documentation for more info on the substr command

```
DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (
   lob_loc     IN    CLOB   CHARACTER SET ANY_CS,
   amount      IN    INTEGER := 32767,
   offset      IN    INTEGER := 1)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 CHARACTER SET lob_loc%CHARSET;
```