# how to select LOB data

Tags: maxdb

I have MaxDB and Java.
I try to select data from table with this request:

```
sql_execute SELECT * FROM SAPPOPDB.T_CHUNK where T_CHUNK.CHUNK_DATA < '10000'
```

but got this response:

> -24988,ERR_SQL: SQL error
>
> -7032,SQL statement not allowed for column of data type LOB

Table structure:

```
DOMAIN_HASH      KEY  NUMBER            10   0  SEL+UPD+  0  1  1  25.04.2014  17:31:17  25.04.2014  17:31:17
DOMAIN_COUNTER   KEY  NUMBER            10   0  SEL+UPD+  0  2  2  25.04.2014  17:31:17  25.04.2014  17:31:17
SESSION_HASH     KEY  NUMBER            10   0  SEL+UPD+  0  3  3  25.04.2014  17:31:17  25.04.2014  17:31:17
SESSION_COUNTER  KEY  NUMBER            10   0  SEL+UPD+  0  4  4  25.04.2014  17:31:17  25.04.2014  17:31:17
CHUNK_NAME       KEY  VARCHAR  UNICODE  200     SEL+UPD+     5  5  25.04.2014  17:31:17  25.04.2014  17:31:17
CHUNK_DATA       OPT  LONG     BYTE             SEL+UPD+     6     25.04.2014  17:31:17  25.04.2014  17:31:17
```

Please help, how can I get `CHUNK_DATA` from table?

Thank you

Comment: Is this Oracle or MySQL? You've selected both tags, but these are separate DBMS platforms.

Comment: MaxDB like to Oracle db

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to query a CLOB column in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790379/how-to-query-a-clob-column-in-oracle)

Comment: but how convert data '10000' to blob, maxdb use other function blob2varchar don't support