# How to convert CLOB to VARCHAR2 in oracle to java?

Tags: java, oracle

In pl/sql,I write the code and it runs well.But when I using java,it tells me wrong.How to fix it?

```
select clobcontent,to_char(clobcontent),DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(clobcontent,4000,1),
CAST(clobcontent AS VARCHAR2) from t_student
```

If I use `to_char` in the java,it is wrong.

```
ORA-64203:Destination buffer too small to hold CLOB data after character set conversion.
```

So I try to cut out the colbcontent.I use `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR`,but it is still wrong.

```
ora-06502 pl/sql numeric or value error character string buffer too small.
```

What's wrong?My sql statement runs well in pl/sql developer but runs wrong in   java.

Comment: post the java code you tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query a CLOB column in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790379/how-to-query-a-clob-column-in-oracle)