# Which Hybris D.B. Table contain product description

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I need to get the Product description manually from database, so please suggest which table it contains.

**My Finding**

**Productslp** table contains **p_dscription** column but that is **clob** datatype and I am unable to get the data from that.

Comment: Actually productslp.p_description is the column you are looking for, however it is CLOB because you are using Oracle i guess, otherwise it will be TEXT or LONGVARCHAR...

Comment: Check this post, how to convert CLOB to STR : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790379/how-to-query-a-clob-column-in-oracle

Comment: Why actually do you need it directly from the DB ? Can't you export it via flexsearch of impexes ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, you raise a support ticket with SAP Product support, since it may be a matter of correct `Oracle JDBC driver`.

We use `HANA DB` and had the same issue, they provided me with an updated driver and that resolved the issue for me.

Alternatively you can check the description in `backoffice/hmc` if that is an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can get using the SQL tab in hac with this query.

Select  ps.p_description,ps.p_summary from products as p join productslp as ps ON p.pk=ps.itempk where pk=8796158722049

[See the image below for result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeQVM.png)