# Retrieve CLOB from oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get a CLOB out of an Oracle database and I can't get it to work.

I have tried

```
TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(FieldName,0,4000))
```

and

```
select dbms_lob.substr(FieldName,4000,1) part1, 
       dbms_lob.substr(FieldName,4001,6000) part2
```

then Concatenate with no joy.

I am quite new to this, can anyone assist?

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790379/how-to-query-a-clob-column-in-oracle      ,   might help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query a CLOB column in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790379/how-to-query-a-clob-column-in-oracle)

Comment: What do you mean by "get a CLOB out of an Oracle database"? Out, where? To a file? to Excel? to what, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In your first answer, you tried using to_char(substr())..  I think you don't need the to_char.  substr should return a character string.
I recently worked on a project to create an email.  Database was Oracle 11g.  The email text body was stored in a CLOB.  I wrote a (standard) C program to do the job.
First, I declared a character array of 30k bytes for the email body.  My SQL was straightforward:

```
EXEC SQL
  Select txt_email_body
    into :mailText
    from email_request
   where  .....
```

txt_email_body was the CLOB.  mailText was the 30k char array in the C program.