# check if clob contains string oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

currently i have query with this code `to_char(CLOB_COLUM) like %s` but the following wont work for very big clob. Is there another solution to check if this column contains some string. Using oracle 11.2.0.4.0

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [`DBMS_LOB.INSTR( clob_value, pattern [, offset [, occurrence]] )`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/appdev.901/a89852/dbms_17b.htm):

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  DBMS_LOB.INSTR( clob_column, 'string to match' ) > 0;
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  clob_column LIKE '%string to match%';
```

Comment: first worked, the second is not working had tried that aproach also in past, not sure why but i think the second looks only like to_char first 4000 chars

Comment: Can you please tell how can search for a string which doesn't exist in a clob?

Comment: @user3384231 Please read the documentation for `DBMS_LOB.INSTR()` linked in the answer. It tells you the return value if the pattern is not found and you can just use that as a filter rather than `> 0` for when the pattern is found.

Comment: @MT0: thank you. When it is = 0 that searches for the pattern not found.

Answer (score 5):

Base on MT0's answer. I test which way is efficient.

The **CLOB Column** length is **155018** and search for **32 length** string.

Here is my test.

```
| INSTR  | LIKE  |
|:-------|------:|
| 0.857  |0.539  |
| 0.127  |0.179  |
| 1.635  |0.534  |
| 0.511  |0.818  |
| 0.429  |1.038  |
| 1.586  |0.772  |
| 0.461  |0.172  |
| 0.126  |1.379  |
| 1.068  |1.088  |
| 1.637  |1.169  |
| 0.5    |0.443  |
| 0.674  |0.432  |
| 1.201  |0.135  |
| 0.419  |2.057  |
| 0.731  |0.462  |
| 0.787  |1.956  |
```

[image]

The average time of **INSTR**  is 0.797.

The average time of **LIKE**  is 0.823.

Comment: This is a tiny sample size; there is a significant variance in the timings for both answers; and the mean is equal within a tiny margin (which is significantly less than the variance in the results). Therefore the conclusion from this should be that there is not enough data and you cannot conclude with any certainty if one method is more performant than the other. Just use whichever method you find easiest to comprehend/maintain/document as the performance appears to be roughly equal.

Answer (score 1):

USE `DBMS_LOB.COMPARE()`

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  DBMS_LOB.COMPARE( clob_column, 'string to match' ) = 0;
```

Return Value
INTEGER: 0 if the comparison succeeds, nonzero if not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the column's value and Oracle returns `ORA-22835` (buffer too small) for `WHERE  clob_column LIKE '%string to match%'`, then you should to apply some workaround.

The combination of `DBMS_LOB.instr` and `DBMS_LOB.substr` could be a solution. See e.g. [this Stackoverflow tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37026285/1105899). So, in your case:

```
SELECT DBMS_LOB.substr(your_clob_column, DBMS_LOB.instr(your_clob_column,'string to match'), 1) AS Text
FROM your_table
WHERE DBMS_LOB.instr(your_clob_column, 'string to match') > 0
```