# CLOB value return in PLSQL oracle : invalid LOB locator specified: ORA-22275

Tags: plsql

I am getting below error while returning a CLOB from a stored procedure:

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: invalid LOB locator specified: ORA-22275

What is the solution to get a clob output?  (Also, I am using Toad)

Plsql code :

```
PROCEDURE resp               (p_code   IN     VARCHAR2,
                              p_xml_out   IN OUT CLOB,
                              p_rec        IN OUT int_cms_details%ROWTYPE)
   IS
      l_xml   CLOB := '  ';
   BEGIN
     SELECT XMLELEMENT (
          "rootelement",
          XMLELEMENT ("status",
                      DECODE (column, 'SUCCESS', 'SUCCESS', 'FAIL')),
          XMLELEMENT (
             "Questions",
             XMLAGG (
                XMLELEMENT (
                   "Question",
                   (XMLFOREST (col1 as "Code",
                               col2 as "Description")))))).getclobval ()
                               into l_xml
   FROM table;
        p_xml_out := l_xml;                             

END res;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query a CLOB column in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790379/how-to-query-a-clob-column-in-oracle)

Comment: When I execute it as a Declare block and print the output, the o/p is correct in CLOB format. However, when I am calling the procedure from a web service it throws - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: invalid LOB locator specified: ORA-22275. Error seems to be occurring from the PLSQL block. Do I need to do some conversion before sending the output? Pls suggest a workaround?

Comment: Show the code where do you call the procedure