# How to display text in a CLOB with a DSL request of type SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

SELECT TEST FROM REGISTRE WHERE ID_REGISTRE = 1256

-TEST is CLOB but I want to display the text that is inside with a SQL query in Oracle

The query works but it displays (HUGECLOB).

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790379/how-to-query-a-clob-column-in-oracle answer your question?

Comment: The query doesn't *display* anything, it returns the data that client software need to process. You need to setup the tool you use to fetch clob data for display (generally it is three dots or a double click in an IDE)